# Is it possible to convert audio to midi with the shell?

Tags: shell, audio, conversion, midi

Some might say this doesn't work, but it does, [this website](http://www.ofoct.com/audio-converter/convert-wav-or-mp3-ogg-aac-wma-to-midi.html) does what I want. Can you do this with any common tool like `ffmpeg`? Or maybe there is a python script somewhere? I couldn't find anything on the net.

Comment: Have you tried sox? (I'm not sure it can do midi)

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852102/software-to-convert-audio-to-midi .. look at the software **WaoN**, it hasn't been updated in years but says it accomplishes what you're looking for: http://waon.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [`waon`](https://github.com/kichiki/WaoN):

```
waon -i inputfile -o outputfile.mid
```

Comment: You should've let Nick Weinberg post this answer and accept it. Like that it's a little unfair...

Comment: @polemon He posted his comment 3 months ago. I got the solution from his comment, but since he didn't post an answer I did it myself.

Comment: @polemon not at all. Answers posted as comments are fair game. DisplayName did the right thing, now this question has an answer that can be voted on instead of remaining unanswered with the solution hidden in the comments.

Comment: @terdon and StackOverflow deleted comments in the past, the support told me that they can remove comments without any reason: `Comments are meant to be temporary and can be deleted at any time and for any reason, or even for no reason at all. You should not expect information in comments to stick around indefinitely.`